# How to implement OAuth2.0 using client credentials grant-type in a way that it supports Json raw body with token request in c#

Tags: oauth-2.0, webapi, clientcredential

My project is a web api project which is using owin for generating token after authentication. it is built using asp.net framework.

1. It currently accepts token request in below format -

   var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:63202/1.0/token");
   client.Timeout = -1;
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
   request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
   request.AddParameter("client_id", "12345667");
   request.AddParameter("client_secret", "secret");
2. I want my API to support Json raw body instead of URL encoded one with the token request as below -

   var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:63202/1.0/token");
   client.Timeout = -1;
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
   request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
   var body = @"{" + "\n" +
   @"  "grant_type": "client_credentials"," + "\n" +@" "client_id": "1234567890""," + "\n" +@"client_secret": "channelsintegration123456789012345" + "\n" +
   @"}"
   request.AddParameter("application/json", body,  ParameterType.RequestBody);

Issue - When the request is made and ValidateClientAuthentication() method is hit, the context doesn't have client id and client secret when I make the above (#2) request.